# Getting InflateException in Mashmallow working fine in Lollipop

Tags: android

My problem occurs when an activity (login activity in my case- you can guess the codes all are basic) called from a splash screen (using) a thread.

When I avoid the splash and call the Login Activity straight from launcher it is working fine, but it returns this error when i try to place the splash infront of it.

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class

Bu it is working fine in Lollipop devices, When I test with Marshmallow Emulator the error occurs. Anybody have any idea?

For more details:

I am using AppCompatActivity in the class and this is the manifest section

```
        </activity>

        <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

    </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
```

Error: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dev.jashan.myapplication/com.dev.jashan.myapplication.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class

[image]

**Full Stack**

```
12-05 00:23:01.349 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-05 00:23:01.349 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Late-enabling JIT
12-05 00:23:01.356 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
12-05 00:23:01.397 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.dev.jashan.myapplication-1/lib/x86
12-05 00:23:01.436 11694-11709/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
12-05 00:23:01.439 11694-11709/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
12-05 00:23:01.439 11694-11709/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
12-05 00:23:01.598 11694-11705/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8757(552KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(80KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 32MB/32MB, paused 19.333ms total 49.138ms
12-05 00:23:01.659 11694-11725/com.dev.jashan.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-05 00:23:01.666 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xabfbd760, tid 11694
12-05 00:23:01.701 11694-11725/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-05 00:23:01.822 11694-11725/com.dev.jashan.myapplication W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-05 00:23:01.822 11694-11725/com.dev.jashan.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad7e0300, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-05 00:23:04.697 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
12-05 00:23:04.699 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
12-05 00:23:04.709 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 374(79KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 8% free, 33MB/36MB, paused 973us total 7.599ms
12-05 00:23:04.712 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
12-05 00:23:04.720 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 130(11KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 33MB/37MB, paused 955us total 7.013ms
12-05 00:23:04.722 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
12-05 00:23:04.729 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 20(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 33MB/37MB, paused 935us total 6.393ms
12-05 00:23:04.731 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 31MB allocation
12-05 00:23:04.731 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
12-05 00:23:04.738 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 33MB/37MB, paused 1.111ms total 6.810ms
12-05 00:23:04.738 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 33177612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 30MB until OOM"
12-05 00:23:04.738 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
12-05 00:23:04.739 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
12-05 00:23:04.749 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(576B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 33MB/37MB, paused 994us total 9.553ms
12-05 00:23:04.750 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
12-05 00:23:04.757 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 32(1320B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 33MB/37MB, paused 945us total 6.256ms
12-05 00:23:04.757 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
12-05 00:23:04.767 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5(128B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 33MB/37MB, paused 1.007ms total 9.957ms
12-05 00:23:04.769 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 31MB allocation
12-05 00:23:04.769 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
12-05 00:23:04.778 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 33MB/37MB, paused 937us total 8.345ms
12-05 00:23:04.781 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 33177612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 30MB until OOM"
12-05 00:23:04.781 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.dev.jashan.myapplication, PID: 11694
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dev.jashan.myapplication/com.dev.jashan.myapplication.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.dev.jashan.myapplication.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:49)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.dev.jashan.myapplication.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:49) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.dev.jashan.myapplication.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:49) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 33177612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 30MB until OOM
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3948)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.dev.jashan.myapplication.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:49) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
12-05 00:23:04.782 11694-11694/com.dev.jashan.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. In this case, it would include the full stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare screen shot added.

Comment: Please provide the **full stack trace** (not part of it) as **text** (not a nearly-unreadable screenshot).

Comment: @CommonsWare Hope you can help me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 33177612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 30MB until OOM
```

Somewhere, you have a `LinearLayout`, probably one on which you have an `android:background` attribute. That background's decoded resource is 33,177,612 bytes. This is **much too big**. A full 1080p image is only 8MB, not ~32MB.

Usually, this is caused by a combination of having too large of an image in the first place and having it in the wrong resource directory (e.g., `res/drawable/`).

You are going to need to identify this `LinearLayout`, identify the image that is causing the crash, and then doing something to not try to allocate so much memory, such as:

- removing the background entirely
- using a smaller image
- having different versions of the image in different resource sets by density (e.g., `res/drawable-mdpi/`, `res/drawable-hdpi/`), so that Android does not need to try to resample the image to fix up the density
- having the image in `res/drawable-nodpi/`, so Android does not bother trying to resample it ever

Comment: Thank you very much, let me check.